# AWS-SNS publish() method not sending any messages to phone number

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-sns

I have used `aws-sdk` in node express to send the verification code to the phone number I referred [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-sending-sms.html) to implement it. here I get the response but do not get any messages on the phone.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  region: "region",
  accessKeyId: "ACCESS_KEY",
  secretAccessKey: "SECRET_KEY",
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let phone_no = "+91876214****";
  let random = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  const YOUR_MESSAGE = `Your verification code is ${random}`;

  let params = {
    Message: YOUR_MESSAGE,
    PhoneNumber: phone_no,
    MessageAttributes: {
      "AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType": {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "Transactional",
      },
  };

  let publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: "2010-03-31" })
    .publish(params)
    .promise();

  publishTextPromise
    .then(function (data) {
      return res.json({ id: data.MessageId, otp: random });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      return res.send(err.stack);
    });
});
```

is anything I'm doing wrong, new to this aws-sns concept.

here i logged the `publishTextPromise` i get response as `Promise { <pending> }`

Comment: Is your number satisfy E.164 format requirements? Try sending this code without message attributes in the param.https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascript/example_code/sns/sns_publishsms.js


Also recommendation would be to use javascript sdk v3 as it allows await and it worked for me. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sns/index.html

Comment: is there need to verify the phone number in AWS to send the message?

Comment: No. documents doesn't mention the need

Comment: my phone number satisfies the E.164 format and also implemented the await keyword for this but still not getting any message to the specified phone number

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Success` result from api but message is not received. You need to check SNS logs.

On SNS console, you can see `Text messaging (SMS)` under **Mobile** section. If you don't enable status logging, firstly edit preferences on `Delivery status logs` section then on new page create an IAM Role (SNSSuccessFeedback) with *Success sample rate 100%*.

You can find error on cloudwatch.

Potential problem. `You account is in the SMS sandbox` in the region which you used.

[image]

If you see any message like ☝️, You can add your phone number on sandbox destination phone number.

[image]

Then sandbox will send you a verify code, when you put it on AWS console. Then you will be able to receive messages from SNS.